# Lock The Phone in Android programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I was trying to lock the device and trying to enable it by using the following code but it is not working.I have also taken the two following permisson and not showing that that phone is locked...I also tried to unlock it again.

```
public class LockPhoneActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    Button lock, unlock;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        lock = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        unlock = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        lock.setOnClickListener(this);
        unlock.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.button1:

            KeyguardManager mgr = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
            KeyguardLock lock = mgr.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
            lock.reenableKeyguard();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Locked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            break;

        case R.id.button2:

            KeyguardManager mgr1 = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
            KeyguardLock lock1 = mgr1.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);

            lock1.disableKeyguard();

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I have also taken the following permission...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to Lock Android Phone Screen Programmaticllay,
just check below tutorial.

[**Lock Android Phone Screen Programmtically**](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/03/lock-phone-screen-programmtically.html)

i have written simple application to achieve this.

let me comment if you get any trouble with my solution

Comment: Yes, Worked Well for me.... I want to lock the device with a password,if possible provide me a better link.

Comment: my pleasure :)... ya sure for password enabled you should check [Device Administration API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html#overview), it may help you

Comment: Can you provide a full tutorial or Project ??

Comment: @RDC thank you very very much, I really need it! but unfortunately as I make a project with those codes it gets force closed...may you please share the whole project ?

Comment: @RDC or help me somehow?

Answer (score 3):

you also could do it over device admin

```
DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
mDPM.lockNow();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mKeyGuardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
mLock = mKeyGuardManager.newKeyguardLock("alarmRecieve");
((KeyguardLock) mLock).reenableKeyguard();
```

Comment: I have tried your posted code but its still not working... :(KeyguardManager mgr = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
   KeyguardLock lock = mgr.newKeyguardLock("alarmRecieve");
   ((KeyguardLock) lock).reenableKeyguard();

Comment: "alarmRecieve" replace with your activity name

Comment: @nafiz have you got the solution to your problem ?